# Recreating a logo which uses Helvetica Neue

Tags: fonts, xetex

This is the logo I'm trying to recreate:

[image]

So far, my best results have come via `helvet`/`phv` (I don't need colors):

[image]

As you can see, it's just not quite there. Is there a better, built-in font I can use? I prefer TeX-native solutions, even though I have access to the "proper" Helvetica Neue. I'de also prefer not to stretch text, if possible.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv} % Arial
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} % Arial

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{flushright}
\resizebox{!}{1cm}{\textbf{Die drei}}\
\vspace{2mm}

\resizebox{!}{1.3cm}{\textbf{???}}\raisebox{8mm}{\large \textregistered}\
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you're loading `fontspec` you should be using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX (and you shouldn't load `fontenc`) in which case why not just use the system Helvetica Neue font?

Comment: The text in your image *is*  stretched or condensed.

Comment: @AlanMunn: I am using xelatex already, I see that I forgot to add the tag and will try to fix.

What do you mean by "system"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage of xelatex is that you can use the system fonts immediately, with a single `\setmainfont` invocation.  What are the system fonts?  They are the fonts available to any application on your computer.  For example, on a windows system, they are the fonts that would appear in the fonts pull-down menu on MSWord (spit!) were I to invoke it. (On a Windows system, they reside in C:\Windows\Fonts)

Many fonts are built in to my Windows system, including `Haettenschweiler`, which bears a passing resemblance to the font you seek.  If you find another better font, already on your system, or downloadable to it, just change the name of the `\setmainfont` argument to that other font.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setmainfont{Haettenschweiler}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{flushright}
\resizebox{!}{1cm}{\textbf{Die drei}}\
\vspace{2mm}

\resizebox{!}{1.2cm}{%
  \textbf{?\textcolor{red}{?}\textcolor{green!1!cyan!99!blue}{?}}}%
  \smash{\rlap{\raisebox{8mm}{\LARGE \textregistered}}}
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @KristianNordestgaard Maybe BIllboard (http://moorstation.org/typoasis/designers/steffmann/samples/b/billboard.htm).  Also, Topic Bold (https://www.whatfontis.com/URW-Topic-Std-Bold.font) is close, but the "i" dots are circular.  Same with Pilsen Plakat (http://moorstation.org/typoasis/designers/steffmann/samples/p/pilsen.htm)

Comment: Perfect answer!

Answer (score 2):

This seems very like it:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=12]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}

\definecolor{logored}{RGB}{226,30,45}
\definecolor{logoblue}{RGB}{0,160,224}

\setmainfont{Helvetica Neue}
\newfontface{\neuecondbold}{Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold}

\begin{document}

\raggedleft\fontsize{48}{48}\neuecondbold\offinterlineskip
Die drei\hphantom{\normalfont\normalsize\textregistered}\\[2pt]
?\textcolor{logored}{?}\textcolor{logoblue}{?}%
  \raisebox{30pt}{\normalfont\normalsize\textregistered}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Probably the font has been artificially condensed some more.